# Vectorized way of checking dataframe values (as key, value tuple) against a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, boolean

I'd like to create a column in my dataframe that checks whether the values in one column are the dictionary values of *another* column which comprises the dictionary keys, like so:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Model': ['Corolla', 'Civic', 'Accord', 'F-150'],
                   'Make': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Toyota', 'Ford']})
dic = {'Prius':'Toyota', 'Corolla':'Toyota', 'Civic':'Honda', 
       'Accord':'Honda', 'Odyssey':'Honda', 'F-150':'Ford', 
       'F-250':'Ford', 'F-350':'Ford'}
df

Out [3]:
     Model    Make
0  Corolla  Toyota
1    Civic   Honda
2   Accord  Toyota
3    F-150    Ford
```

And after applying a function, or whatever it takes, I'd like to see:

```
Out [10]:
     Model    Make   match
0  Corolla  Toyota    TRUE
1    Civic   Honda    TRUE
2   Accord  Toyota   FALSE
3    F-150    Ford    TRUE
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried making a function that is passed a tuple which would be the two columns, but I don't think I'm passing the arguments correctly:

```
def is_match(make, model):
  try:
    has_item = dic[make] == model
  except KeyError:
    has_item = False
  return(has_item)

df[['Model', 'Make']].apply(is_match)

results in:
TypeError: ("is_match() missing 1 required positional 
argument: 'model'", 'occurred at index Model')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using `map`

```
df.assign(match=df.Model.map(dic).eq(df.Make))
Out[129]: 
     Make    Model  match
0  Toyota  Corolla   True
1   Honda    Civic   True
2  Toyota   Accord  False
3    Ford    F-150   True
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer in terms of intuition **and** performance.  See timings below.

Comment: @piRSquared appreciate the timing !! :-)

Comment: Thanks to you and @piRSquared! However, I haven't marked as the answer yet because I'm feverishly attempting to get my real dict to work here. It's created from a .csv and in the form {key: [value]} instead of {key: value}, thus everything is False

Comment: Then do `new_dic = {k: v[0] for k, v in dic.items()}`

Comment: @piRSquared you're the best!

Answer (score 3):

## Comprehension

```
df.assign(match=[dic.get(md, '') == mk for mk, md in df.values])

     Make    Model  match
0  Toyota  Corolla   True
1   Honda    Civic   True
2  Toyota   Accord  False
3    Ford    F-150   True
```

---

## `dict.items` and `in`

```
items = dic.items()
df.assign(match=[t[::-1] in items for t in map(tuple, df.values)])

     Make    Model  match
0  Toyota  Corolla   True
1   Honda    Civic   True
2  Toyota   Accord  False
3    Ford    F-150   True
```

---

## `isin`

```
df.assign(match=pd.Series(list(map(tuple, df.values[:, ::-1]))).isin(dic.items()))

     Make    Model  match
0  Toyota  Corolla   True
1   Honda    Civic   True
2  Toyota   Accord  False
3    Ford    F-150   True
```

---

## Numpy Structured Arrays

```
dtype = [('Make', '<U6'), ('Model', '<U7')]
a = np.array([tuple(r) for r in df.values], dtype)
b = np.array(list(dic.items()), dtype[::-1])

df.assign(match=np.in1d(a, b))

     Make    Model  match
0  Toyota  Corolla   True
1   Honda    Civic   True
2  Toyota   Accord  False
3    Ford    F-150   True
```

---

## Timing Comparison

### Conlcusions

@wen's method is an order of magnitude better!

### Functions

```
def wen(df, dic):
    return df.assign(match=df.Model.map(dic).eq(df.Make))

def maxu(df, dic):
    return df.assign(match=df[['Make', 'Model']].sum(axis=1).isin(set([v+k for k, v in dic.items()])))

def pir1(df, dic):
    return df.assign(match=[dic.get(md, '') == mk for mk, md in df.values])

def pir2(df, dic):
    items = dic.items()
    return df.assign(match=[t[::-1] in items for t in map(tuple, df.values)])

def pir3(df, dic):
    return df.assign(match=pd.Series(list(map(tuple, df.values[:, ::-1]))).isin(dic.items()))

def pir4(df, dic):
    dtype = [('Make', '<U6'), ('Model', '<U7')]
    a = np.array([tuple(r) for r in df.values], dtype)
    b = np.array(list(dic.items()), dtype[::-1])

    return df.assign(match=np.in1d(a, b))
```

### Back Test

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
    np.nan, [10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    'wen maxu pir1 pir2 pir3 pir4'.split()
)

for i in res.index:
    m = dict(dic.items())
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = f'{j}(d, m)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import {j}, m, d'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=200)
```

## Results

```
res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0)

            wen       maxu       pir1       pir2       pir3       pir4
10     2.041111   2.799885   1.000000   1.032221   1.432887   1.174196
30     1.544264   2.417550   1.000000   1.043218   1.336503   1.003284
100    1.037501   1.843029   1.000000   1.066310   1.319942   1.191763
300    1.000000   2.373917   1.726667   2.009198   2.193276   2.424844
1000   1.000000   3.962928   3.764808   3.932539   4.099261   4.971527
3000   1.000000   6.250289   6.311701   6.740862   6.258989   7.791234
10000  1.000000   9.014925  10.110949  10.964482  10.347168  13.407998
30000  1.000000  10.410604  11.682759  13.113974  11.877862  16.000993
```

Answer (score 2):

yet another option:

```
In [38]: df['match'] = df[['Make','Model']] \
                         .sum(axis=1) \
                         .isin(set([v+k for k,v in dic.items()]))

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
     Make    Model  match
0  Toyota  Corolla   True
1   Honda    Civic   True
2  Toyota   Accord  False
3    Ford    F-150   True
```

Comment: Lot's of methods... timing incoming (-:

Comment: @piRSquared I need a tutorial on how to generate your timing chart.